# Matlab Fraction to Floating Point

Tags: matlab, floating-point, numerical

After using the 'solve' function on an equation with one variable, it seems like Matlab doesn't like using floating point. So, my answer is

```
ans = -2515439103678008769411809280/29019457930552314063110978530889-1/232155663444418512504887828247112*13479465975722384794797850090594238631144539220477565900842902305^(1/2)
```

and I'm not sure what the best way to convert it to an understandable decimal is.  The best way I have so far is

```
eval(char(ans))
```

(which gives me -0.5002 for those keeping track), but I'm not really happy with that solution.

Can anyone suggest something better?

Comment: The dislike for floating-point is perfectly understandable for a mathematical program. Usually you want exact results and not some approximation.

Comment: I suppose so, but this is mainly so I can easily sanity check my answers before plugging into Simulink to do its numerical integration. Also, eval wouldn't work on vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the [very next page](http://matlab.izmiran.ru/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/ch11_st4.html) I looked at had the answer. It's the 'double' function:

```
double(ans)
```